# Inserting node replaces previous node in python

Tags: python, xpath

I would like to append multiple values to this node (if it occours), but when I do this productid2 replaces productid1. Is there a way to return separate product-id items?

```
           for node in tree.xpath( '//map/topicmeta' ):
                node.insert(5, othermeta)                       
                othermeta.set("name", "product-id")
                othermeta.attrib['content'] = meta_productid1

                othermeta.set("name", "product-id")
                othermeta.attrib['content'] = meta_productid2
```

Comment: one node may have only one name - create two nodes

Answer (score 0):

you can use a `list` or `tuple` to store multiple items:

```
othermeta.attrib['content'] = []
othermeta.attrib['content'].append(meta_productid1)
othermeta.attrib['content'].append(meta_productid2)
```

or

```
othermeta.attrib['content'] = [meta_productid1, meta_productid2]
othermeta.attrib['content'] = (meta_productid1, meta_productid2)
```

you can get them by:

```
id1, id2 = othermeta.attrib['content']
```

---

if type of `othermeta.attrib['content']` is restricted to `str`, you can concat `id1` `id2` to one `str`, and parse it where you use:

store:

```
othermeta.attrib['content'] = ','.join([meta_productid1, meta_productid2])
```

use:

```
id1, id2 = othermeta.attrib['content'].split(',')
```

hope I don't have misunderstanding about your question.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunately by doing this I get the error: Arguments must be bytes or Unicode, got "list"

Comment: I have updated a new method, `join` and `split`, you can try this.